# Почему на http://start.spring.io поддерживают Kotlin и не поддерживают Scala

Tags: kotlin, scala

Какая причина может быть что на ресурсе http://start.spring.io нет поддержки **Scala** но есть поддержка **Kotlin** и даже **Groovy**?

Comment: Scala plugin для Gradle решает вопрос инструкция по ссылке -  http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2014/03/spring-boot-and-scala.html

Comment: Интересный подход )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще, данный вопрос уже обсуждался в виде *issue* к проекту **initializr**: https://github.com/spring-io/initializr/issues/393

Если кратко - не видно смысла в поддержке Scala в настоящее время.

Цитата:

> Given the response of the Scala community to the Spring Scala project, I don't think that this will be time well spent.
>
> *Учитывая реакцию Scala-сообщества на проект Spring Scala, не думаю, что это [реализация поддержки Scala в initializr] будет хорошей тратой времени.*

Comment: То есть Scala из-за этого теряет некоторое количество сторонников?

Answer (score 2):

У Scala достаточное комьюнити чтоб иметь свои фреймворки, и использовать в полной мере свою философию написания кода.

Чтоб писать на Scala - не нужно знать Java (желательно - но не обязательно). Использование Spring не на Java - вынуждает знать оба языка.

Видимо не нашлось желающих тратить свое время на добавление костылей в Spring. Ну действительно, зачем на это тратить время?

Ну а вообще, этот вопрос надо адресовать к людям из start.spring.io, а не сюда.

Comment: можно и на start.spring.io но там разве по-русски происходит общение?

Answer (score 1):

Это фреймворк не ориентирован на этот язык. Для **scala** есть другие фреймворки. Например, [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/).

Comment: Поддержка scala дала бы больший прирост комьюнити

Comment: @Vitalii почему вы так думаете? Play ничем не хуже Spring - зачем люди будут переходить на Spring?

Comment: я так не считаю что люди должны переходить с Play на Spring )

Comment: @Vitalii а почему будет больший прирост?